# Pick file via Intent then Delete onActivityResult

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I would like to open a directory, after which I should able to pick a file then delete it. This is my code to open the directory:

```
public void openDirectory() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/drugdiy/doc");
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"), 0);
    }
```

I am stuck with how to pass the `uri` to `onActivityResult` so that I can delete it?

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 0: {
                Uri uri = 
                File file = new File(uri.getPath());
                file.delete();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you read [the documentation for `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT), you will see:

> Input: getType() is the desired MIME type to retrieve. **Note that no URI is supplied in the intent, as there are no constraints on where the returned data originally comes from.**

(emphasis added)

So, your first code snippet will work on few devices.

Second, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` does not have to return to you a file, let alone one that you can delete.

[There are many file-picker libraries available for Android](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/35). Use one. They should give you a `File` back, and you can then call `delete()` on the `File`.